# The Rediscovered Torah Scroll in the times of King Yoshiyahu

Tags: sefer-torah, mesorah-tradition, melachim-kings-book-of

The following question was asked here a bunch of years ago, however it wasn't treated with any great sources or analysis, so here I am attempting to give the topic another shot. In Melachim 2, 22: and Divrei Hayamim 2, 34: We learn about how Chilkiyahu discovered a Scroll. It was quickly discovered that his scroll was the written by the hand of Moses. Rashi says it was Sefer Devarim. Many other commentaries say it was the entire Torah. There is another opinion that it was just a small part of the Torah (which includes the Curses) in a scroll designated for the King of Israel. Either way, the story seems difficult to understand exactly. The Radak is of the opinion that the Torah was forgotten from Klal Yisroel. From a historical perspective, it seems quite difficult to even propose that this means that this means all aspects of the Torah. It seems that according to the Radak's understanding, all of the Torah was warped on a fundamental level, in a way that removes all connection to a Monotheistic message. The Rashba in his tshuvos also deals with this question, albeit asked differently. In his case he's responding to a challenge from a Muslim trying to prove from the story that the Oral Tradition of Chazal is fabricated. After much personal analysis of the topic, it's clear to me that no matter how one understands it, the only framework in which the entire episode makes any sense, in one in which there was always some sort of body of people that clung (possibly in secret) to the true tradition of the Torah. These Sages never lost anything, however they were shunned and possibly persecuted by the rest of the society. King Yoshiyahu saw through the lies of the society and although he wasn't so knowledgeable, he wished to live in accordance with the Torah of the few great people left in the group of righteous Torah Followers. That's why he began to try clearing out some of the foreign altars. Obviously though, fighting against a rebellious society is a daunting task, and until he was presented with the Scroll opened to the verse "Vehashem yolech eschem..." He became invigorated and inspired with courage and began a full-fledged national return to God. This is truly the most rational way to understand the story. With all this being said, I feel that there still remains a big question. The fact of the matter is, that the acknowledgement of such an event seems to leave open some room to claim that although this is the Navi's representation of the story, the truth is that our version of Judaism was indeed only first introduced at that point. There are many sources that discuss the following, but one thorough and early source, namely the Sefer Hachinuch, literally spends his entire Introduction speaking about how the fact that we have a national testimony claiming to be an unbroken chain back to Matan Torah, is an incredibly important and strong fact of evidence for our religions claims to authenticity. So yes, even though his point still holds quite strong according to the simple understanding of the event (meaning, there was still a decent following to the original tradition of Torah who continued the chain.) Still, what's a little disturbing is that the story seems to allow room for one to say that in truth there was no tradition whatsoever, and it was simply the later reforming generations that created that narrative. In line with this, one can defend such a possible creation of a new religion by pointing out how the King forced everyone to agree to his new rules as described in the later verses in the above-mentioned books of Nach. Also, the one claiming this argument can maybe explain away all of the irrationalities between such an approach and the narrative of Nach, as mere consequences of a made-up story, and thus according to them the Nach wouldn't even necessarily be implying the existence of a group of Torah steadfast Torah followers. So anyway, my question to you all is, what would you answer to such a challenge to the veracity of our tradition?

For the sake of extra clarity, the reason I say one must understand the story in the framework of the existence of a group of persevering Torah Scholars and followers, is not due to this very question regarding how the Torah was legitimately accepted and it's intricacies subsequently known to all, but rather in terms of the small details of the story making sense in itself, I believe that' the only way to make rational sense of it. However, like I said at the end of the previous paragraph, one might argue that all of the small irrationalities and inconsistencies of the story in tself don't point to any ultimate unifying interpretation, but rather represent the fact that the story in fact doesn't make sense in reality and instead was a non-sensical twisting of the truth of what happened.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to condense your question? As for the subject, the sources themselves tell us of prophets who lived at the time following the Torah (Yirmiyahu, Chuldah, etc), so evidently the tradition wasn't lost to everyone.

Comment: A Sefer Torah was discovered in my shul one time. Does that mean before then all mesorah was lost?

Comment: There is no limit to how many paragraph breaks you can use to make your question clearer

Comment: You guys are right, I see that I did a horrible job in terms of clarity. Sorry. Honestly, sometimes I am very bad at getting back to things on forums, but I will try to get back soon and fix this up.

Comment: This appears to be an answer rather than a question. You should either answer the original question or make this a short question and give the answer yourself.

Comment: @sabbahillel I do have to get back to this sometime although I'm not so consistent with responding to online forums in general. However, despite my lack of clarity in this post, I think it is at least clear that it is a question from the end. If you read it carefully as is, you can still see how I explain that my question is not the same question as the original post, rather that despite the fact that I see the story in a way that his question is answered I still find a little difficulty with the fact that the whole episode seems to leave open the possibility...

Comment: ...of deception and thus weakens the strength of our trust in the chain.

Answer (score 3):

Rav Yosef Albo in his famous sefer [Sefer HaIkkarim (Maamar 3:22:1)](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaIkkarim%2C_Maamar_3.22.1?ven=Sefer_Ha-ikkarim,_Jewish_Publication_Society_of_America,_1929&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) explains this at great length. He writes:

> The Torah which we have to-day and which has been handed down to us by unbroken tradition from father to son is the same that was given to Moses on Sinai, without any change. It could not have received change in the time of the first temple when the priests and teachers were in the temple and the Torah was well known to everybody. And though there were among them kings who worshipped idols, they also had prophets during the entire period until the time of the destruction, who admonished the people to observe the Torah. **And as for the great alarm which Josiah felt when the priest Hilkiah found a book of the Torah in the house of the Lord, this does not signify that they had no copy of the Torah, for Jeremiah was alive then.** But the reason was this. Amon and Menasseh were worshippers of idols and offended God, so much so that our Rabbis say, Menasseh cut the names of God out of the Torah and substituted names of idols in their place. Accordingly one of the priests who feared that the king might do the same with the original copy of the Torah which Moses wrote, if it got into his hands, hid it in the walls of the building. Later, in the days of Josiah, who returned to the Lord with all his heart, with all his soul and with all his might in accordance with the law of Moses, they looked for this book and could not find it. And when they repaired the temple, Hilkiah found it in the wall and was very much elated over it, as if he had found a great treasure. He then sent a message to the king, saying, I have found the book of the Law, the well known book which Moses wrote; he did not say I found a book of the law. Now the reason that king Josiah was so alarmed at the find and rent his garments when he heard the words of the book, is as our Rabbis explain in the Jerusalem Talmud. The Torah which Moses wrote was rolled up so that it opened on the beginning of Genesis, whereas the manuscript which they found opened on the verse in Deuteronomy: “The Lord will bring thee, and thy king whom thou shalt set over thee, unto a nation that thou hast not known. .” This is the reason why the king was alarmed, and not because the people had forgotten the Torah, God forbid!

Rav Albo explains that Amon and Menasseh were worshippers of idols, they replaced the name of G-d for names of idols they worshipped, in the scrolls of Torah. He explains that one of the priests wanted to prevent that, and hid the orginal scroll that was written by Moshe Rabbeinu in a wall, that scroll was founded later on, in the story you mentioned. This does however, not mean that there was no tradition before that finding. The mesorah was intact, as Rav Yosef Albo explains.

Comment: Thanks for supplying us with this source. I have seen it before, but I forgot to include in my original post. Honestly, I think there's only one thing that he says, that ultimately talks to my question. That is, when he says that the fact there were Nevi'im alive then, proves that there was Knowledge of Torah also around then (at least in Yermiyahu's case...). The problem is, exactly what a Navi needs to know in order to be a Navi, is not exactly clear according to any open sources in Tanach, (I know what the Rambam says...)

Comment: Also, I once tried looking if there is any proof that Yermiyahu was active as a Navi in the time of this story, and I think it seemed like there was no proof, but I would need to research this again, as that was more than a year ago. Lastly, I think even if we took for granted the requirement of Torah knowledge for being a Navi, still one may claim that Yermiyahu's existence as a Navi wasn't accurate, or Yermiyahu fooled the people and was one of those who perpetrated the beginning of the new religion. Let me be clear, such claims are a joke to me, but I am just looking for suggestions on-

Comment: -methods of disproving such an understanding. But again, to make such silly and radical interpretations is completely baseless.